# Prefill RestKit cache

Tags: ios, caching, restkit

I'd like to ship the app with a file already in the RestKit's cache. How can that be done?
Alternatively, is it possible with RestKit to deserialize a json file from the app bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using CoreData in your App?
If so you want to look at the the `RKManagedObjectSeeder`, which allows you to use jSON text files to populate a seed database which can be shipped with your App.

Alternatively, if not using CoreData, I think you can get it to read JSON text files on launch, but I haven't needed that.

Have a look at the `RESTKit` Twitter example that comes with `RESTKit`, as I believe it has what you need in there.